# How to group array by dimension level?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a tree array, but I want to group the array by dimension so that I can display each level of the tree in its own DIV.

My tree array is:

```
$tree =
array(
    1 => array('id'=>1, 'title'=>'Category 1', 'parent_id'=>0,
        'children'=> array(
            2 => array('id'=>2, 'title'=>'Category 2', 'parent_id'=>1, 'children'=>''),
            3 => array('id'=>3,'title'=>'Category 3','parent_id'=>1,'children'=>''),
            4 => array('id'=>4, 'title'=>'Category 4', 'parent_id'=>1,
                'children'=> array(
                    8 => array('id'=>8, 'title'=>'Category 8', 'parent_id'=>4, 'children'=>''),
                    9 => array('id'=>9, 'title'=>'Category 9', 'parent_id'=>4, 'children'=>''),
                    10 => array('id'=>10, 'title'=>'Category 10', 'parent_id'=>4,
                        'children'=> array(
                            11 => array('id'=>11, 'title'=>'Category 11', 'parent_id'=>10, 'children'=>''),
                            12 => array('id'=>12, 'title'=>'Category 12', 'parent_id'=>10, 'children'=>''),
                            13 => array('id'=>13, 'title'=>'Category 13', 'parent_id'=>10, 'children'=>'')
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    5 => array('id'=>5, 'title'=>'Category 5', 'parent_id'=>0,
        'children'=>array(
            6 => array('id'=>6,'title'=>'Category 6', 'parent_id'=>5, 'children'=>''),
            7 => array('id'=>3,'title'=>'Category 7', 'parent_id'=>5, 'children'=>'')
        )
    )
);
```

I would like to separate each level like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KknYA.jpg). My idea for the grouped output is something like this:

```
$grouped = array(
    0 => array(
        1 => array('id'=>1, 'title'=>'Category 1', 'parent_id'=>0),
        5 => array('id'=>5, 'title'=>'Category 5', 'parent_id'=>0)
    ),
    1 => array(
        2 => array('id'=>2,  'title'=>'Category 2',  'parent_id'=>1),
        3 => array('id'=>3,  'title'=>'Category 3',  'parent_id'=>1),
        4 => array('id'=>4,  'title'=>'Category 4',  'parent_id'=>1),
        6 => array('id'=>6,  'title'=>'Category 6',  'parent_id'=>5),
        7 => array('id'=>3,  'title'=>'Category 7',  'parent_id'=>5)
    ),
    2 => array(
        8 => array('id'=>8,   'title'=>'Category 8',  'parent_id'=>4),
        9 => array('id'=>9,   'title'=>'Category 9',  'parent_id'=>4),
        10 => array('id'=>10, 'title'=>'Category 10', 'parent_id'=>4)
    ),
    3 => array(
        11 => array('id'=>11, 'title'=>'Category 11', 'parent_id'=>10),
        12 => array('id'=>12, 'title'=>'Category 12', 'parent_id'=>10),
        13 => array('id'=>13, 'title'=>'Category 13', 'parent_id'=>10)
    )
);
```

Something else is fine if you have other ideas, but I want to be able to `foreach` the output array and display all the elements of each level in a different DIV.

EX:

```
<div id="box-1">
  Group Array[1]
</div>
<div id="box-2">
  Group Array[2]
</div>
<div id="box-3">
  Group Array[3]
</div>
<div id="box-4">
  Group Array[4]
</div>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: You can implement this recursively. Write a function that adds all information from the current level into a list, then (within that function) call the function itself on the "children" property.

Comment: I edited your question to add the code from the images and clarify what I perceived to be your intended goal. Please feel free to re-edit or roll back the changes if it is not what you had in mind, and if you can add any code you have written to try to accomplish this, it may help to further clarify the question.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry my english is not good.

Comment: No worries. Many times people will edit your grammar if they understand what you're asking. But if you ask more questions in the future, try to include your code in the question rather than linking to images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of a simple recursive function that will separate each level of a tree array.

```
// begin with a reference to an empty array and level 0
function split_levels($branches, &$output = array(), $level = 0) {

    // loop over each element of the current branch
    foreach ($branches as $id => $branch) {

        // if the element has children, make a recursive call with an incremented level
        if ($branch['children']) split_levels($branch['children'], $output, $level + 1);

        // remove the children (this is optional)
        unset($branch['children']);

        // add the element to the output array at the appropriate level
        $output[$level][$id] = $branch;
    }
}
```

Because `$output` is a reference in this function it should be called like this:

```
split_levels($tree, $output);
```

and the results will be in `$output`.